# Chullin 3:7 and Monopterus Cuchia

Tags: science

The Gemara (Niddah 51b) says that there will never exist a fish with scales and no fins. Then comes in the Monopterus Cuchia, a fish which has scales, yet does not possess any fins.

Does anyone have an answer to this? I have been doing some research but did not come up with anything.

Please note that a "fin" in halacha is classified as what the fish uses to swim with, as stated in Chullin 3:7. The Monopterus Cuchia does not, as far as I know, have such fins.

Comment: Maybe it's not a fish? I.e., that the halachic classification of a "fish" is one that either has fins and scales, or only fins. If it doesn't have fins, it's not halachically a fish?

Comment: there seems to be discussion online about the http://daatemet.org.il/en/question/about-the-fish-which-has-no-fin-the-monopterus-cuchia/ http://daatemet.org.il/en/question/your-words-about-fish/ https://www.torchweb.org/torah_detail.php?id=117

Comment: @Harel13, Technically that would be a good answer. Do you know of a source of the classification of a fish? Perhaps it is written somewhere. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @rosends Yes I am aware of Daat Emet's arguments I just want to see if they are correct or not, for there is plenty of proof that Oral Torah is divine and therefore was written with divine wisdom. Surely the Chachamim were not wrong about this case either.

Comment: @Torahlover613 the third link I provided makes a related statement at the end. I was simply filling a gap, as your question indicated that you had not come up with anything in your research.

Comment: @rosends Gotcha, this did clarify that we understand that it has fins, I am just wondering if it even classifies as a fin.

Comment: Maybe some of [this article](https://ohr.edu/this_week/insights_into_halacha/4915) will help.

Comment: Isn't the Monopterus Cuchia a swamp eel?

Answer (score 2):

I have found an answer to my question! Because the Monopterus-Cuchia has scales that are not visible, it does not classify as having scales in halacha.

For sources,  I quote from the oukosher.org site the following: " Both the Aruch HaShulchan and the Tiferes Yisroel mention that the kaskeses must be perceivable by the naked eye from a normal distance in order to be halachicly significant."

I am not sure the exact place they got this from but I also think that it won't be too hard to contact them (or find it ourselves) and get the precise source. But I think for now we can rely on this.

Then for the proof that the Monopterus-Cuchia does not have halachic scales, I refer to fisheriesjournal.org: "Monopterus-Cuchia is a freshwater fish species commonly known as mud eel, swamp eel, cuche or cuchia. It is looks like snake and smooth slimy scale less skin"

For the specific links, see here: (1: https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/an-analysis-of-kaskeses-past-and-present-2/) (2:https://www.fisheriesjournal.com/archives/2019/vol7issue6/PartA/7-5-73-913.pdf )

Comment: I want all of the sources.

Comment: @DoubleAA Sure!

Comment: @DoubleAA I quote from the oukosher.org site the following: " Both the Aruch HaShulchan and the Tiferes Yisroel mention that the kaskeses must be perceivable by the naked eye from a normal distance in order to be halachicly significant." I am not sure the exact place they got this from but I also think that it won't be too hard to contact them and get the precise source. But I think for now we can rely on this.

Comment: Then for the proof that the Monopterus-Cuchia does not have halachic scales, I refer to fisheriesjournal.org: "Monopterus cuchia is a freshwater fish species commonly known as mud eel, swamp eel,
cuche or cuchia. It is looks like snake and smooth slimy scale less skin"

Comment: For the specific links, see here: (1: https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/an-analysis-of-kaskeses-past-and-present-2/) (2:https://www.fisheriesjournal.com/archives/2019/vol7issue6/PartA/7-5-73-913.pdf )

Comment: It's great that you found an answer. You should edit the sources into the answer.

Comment: @Harel13 Bli-neder will do!

Comment: The distinction between the type of scales in eels and fish is apparently that eel scales do not detach like fish scales do. It’s also worth noting that although adult eels do not have fins. The larvae & small juveniles do. See: https://pfeil-verlag.de/publikationen/ophichthys-desilvai-a-poorly-known-synbranchid-eel-from-sri-lanka/

Comment: Here’s a link explaining the unique quality of eel scales: https://niwa.co.nz/freshwater-and-estuaries/nzffd/NIWA-fish-atlas/fish-species/anguillidae

Comment: @YaacovDeane  You are correct scientifically, however, in halacha, any scale that is not visible within a normal distance is not a scale at all, making their nature halachically irrelevant. However, what you have stated is scientifically correct, halacha is ruled based on what you can see with the naked eye (in this case, with a certain distance).

Comment: @YaacovDeane Also fins in halacha are defined as what the fish uses to swim, which the Cuchia does not have, rather it slithers to move. Nevertheless, it doesn't really make a big difference since the Torah says you will never find a fish with scales and no fish, yet you can find a fish with fins and no scales, which although it may have find (scientifically) it does not have scales both in science and halacha. I am open to any arguments.

Comment: I will assume that you are familiar with the famous story of the Brisker Rav and the number of threads in warp and woof in regard to what what is visible with the naked eye. What is obvious to some is missed completely by others. See Yoreh Deah 83 for the emphasis regarding the nature of the scales. The significance of mentioning the fact that the Cuchia, according to the experts who study them, sometimes possess fins and sometimes do not is only to emphasize that the significant siman for them is their type of scales. Not the fins. Consider the related concept of the Chilazon.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Sorry I did not see your comment for a long time. I am a bit confused by your statement. Are you saying that the Halacha for the cuchia is that it does have scales or not?

Comment: I believe this is the subject of the dispute between Rav Herschel Schachter and (I think) Rav Moshe Tendler regarding the kashrus of the swordfish, which has fins as well as microscopic scales. If anyone knows more about this, please comment.